# javascript async await converted to promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have the following code which works fine in Chrome:

```
async function request(config) {
            if (config.url.indexOf('templates/') > -1) {
                await $.getJSON('../../../../version.json', function (data) {
                    config.url += '?v=' + data.version;
                });


            }

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(config);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

Since Internet Explorer does not support async/await, how would I convert the code to use a promise instead of async/await so that it will run in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the code in the getJSON as follows

```
function request(config) {
  if (config.url.indexOf('templates/') > -1) {
    return $.getJSON('../../../../version.json')
      .then(function(data) {
        config.url += '?v=' + data.version;
        return config;
      });
  }
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  deferred.resolve(config);
  return deferred.promise;
}
```